# deep link starts app but says uri is null

Tags: android, android-intent, firebase, intentfilter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have implemented deep linking in my app. Sure enough, when I click on a link from a browser, it opens the app. But when I do

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

both `action` and `data` are null. What would cause such a thing? I imagine the fact that it opens my app means it has a uri.

Here is my intent filter

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="mywebsite.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
            <data
                android:host="mywebsite.com"
                android:scheme="https"/>
            <data
                android:host="/*"
                android:scheme="mywebsite"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the `Intent` from the right `Activity`? (e.g. that your `intent-filter` is set on the launch Activity while you're checking for the Intent on the following Activity)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @KenVanHoeylandt. You nailed it. I was using a Splash activity and had forgotten about that. So thanks for pointing out what might have seen obvious.

Comment: You're welcome! I'll post it as an answer so you can approve of it.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt i faced same issue in this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570290/android-deeplink-intent-returns-null . I am handling deep link in the correct activity but still returns null. Can u please check it out above link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're checking the `Intent` from the right `Activity`.

e.g. that your intent-filter is set on the launch `Activity` while you're checking for the Intent on the following `Activity`

Comment: how to set a dynamic link to open a specific activity in my case it's opening launcher activity.